# controlling the number of background jobs running on UNIX shell

Tags: bash, unix, concurrency

I have a problem where I run scripts of my bash command line one after the other like:

```
./process.sh data1.txt
./process.sh data2.txt
...
./process.sh dataN.txt
```

What I'd like to do is start these as background jobs but only have 10 running at any given time. I can do this in a traditional programming language (am very comfortable using joins, wait style constructs) the question I have is how do I do this using UNIX bash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BG_LIMIT=10
counter=0
for data in data*.txt; do
    ./process.sh $data &
    if (( ++counter % $BG_LIMIT == 0 )); then
        echo "Wating for background jobs to complete..."
        wait
    fi
done
echo "Waiting for any remaining jobs to complete..."
wait
```

Comment: interesting solution, however won't (in your solution) the concurrency possibly exceed BG_LIMIT. If I understand the logic it will wait on every 10th job launched. However there is no guarantee that the jobs will end in sequence.

Comment: No, `wait` is actually waiting for every background job to complete, so it doesn't matter if they'll finish in the order they're spawned or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` as well:

```
$ for x in data*.txt; do echo "$x"; done | xargs -n 1 -P 10 ./process.sh
```

Different variations on the `for` loop are possible: `find`, a simple `echo data*.txt`, etc. The point is to produce a list of file names on standard input for `xargs` to read.